# Reading a file and count it every line

Tags: python

How to count every line.

```
def file_size(filename):
    infile = open(filename)
    for line in infile: 
        return (len(line))  
    infile.close()
```

my code just count tatal words for the first line, and I need count total words in the whole filename.

Comment: Do you know what `return` does?

Comment: What do you mean "count every line"?  Do you mean the length of every line?

Comment: And do you want to return a single number which is the number of lines (or the sum of the lengths of each line), or a list containing the length of each line?

Comment: just want to return the sum of the lengths of the whole lines

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
>>> def file_size(filename):
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    count=0
    total_line=0;
    for line in infile:
            total_line+=1
            for i in line:
                    count+=1
    infile.close()
    return("Total Char = "+str(count)  +"  Total Lines = "+str(total_line))



>>> file_size("Cookie.py")
'Total Char = 238  Total Lines = 5'
```

Comment: This is not a good answer because it tries to close the file after it returns from the function, further misleading/confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def file_size(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return sum(len(_.split()) for _ in f.readlines())
```

Comment: `... in f` is enough, you don't want `... in f.readlines()` here.

Comment: And, `_` is typically only used if the variable is not used... You are using it here to get the length of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
def file_size(filename):
    lines = []
    with open(filename) as infile:
        total = 0
        for line_num, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
            print("The length of line", line_num, "is", len(line))
            lines.append(len(line))
            total += 1
        print("There are a total of", total, "lines")
    return lines, total
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to return the total from the function.

Comment: @SethMMorton: that was not very clear from OP's post, which is why I answer both questions that I thought OP could be asking

Comment: But this function returns `None`... my comment was addressing the fact that I think the OP wanted to return *something* from he function, not print.

Comment: @SethMMorton: I had originally, intentionally left out the return value for not knowing _what_ to return. I opted to print everything so that OP can return the desired value. I have now updated my post, to align it with your comment